Playwright: Set test data based on project
I am trying to set test data based on the project that is configured within the playwright.config.ts.
      projects: [
    {
      name: "NY",
      use: {
        storeID: 1
      },
    },
    {
      name: "NC",
      use: {
        storeID: 888
      },
    },
  ],

I am using a fixture file to do my log-in process based on the project data, but since the application is different for different states, how do I assign the correct json file of data based on the store ID?
Is this something that needs to be done with the test with a conditional?
Here is my fixture file:
import {test as base} from '@playwright/test';
import {LogIn} from '../pom/secureLogInFlow';

export type TestOptions  = {
  storeID: Number;
};

type MyFixtures = {
  logIn: LogIn;
};

export const test = base.extend<TestOptions & MyFixtures>({
  storeID: [ 1, {option: true}],

  logIn: async ({page, storeID}, use) => {
    // Set up the fixture.
    const logIn = new LogIn(page);
    await logIn.goto();
    await logIn.loginWorkFlow(storeID);
    // Use the fixture value in the test.
    await use(logIn);
  },
});
export {expect} from '@playwright/test';


Figured it out.
    export const test = base.extend<TestOptions & MyFixtures>({
  storeID: [1, { option: true }],


  logIn: async ({ page, storeID }, use) => {
    // Set up the fixture.
    const logIn = new LogIn(page);
    await logIn.goto();
    await logIn.loginWorkFlow(storeID);
    // Use the fixture value in the test.
    await use(logIn);
  },
  testData: async ({ storeID }, use) => {
    let NY = await require('../testData/NYTestData.json');
    let NC = await require('../testData/NCTestData.json');
    if (storeID == 1) {
      await use({ ...NY });
    } else {
      await use({ ...NC });
    }
  },
});
export { expect } from '@playwright/test';

